# Get the previous global state data after page reload in angular

Tags: php, node.js, angular, laravel

I used *rxjs* **BehaviourSubject** to store the data globally. But when page reloads all the data stored in it are lost. Is there any way to retrieve  the previous data after page reload without using **localStorage** or **sessionStorage** ????

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer:

No.

#### Long answer:

Your BehaviourSubject stores it's data in memory during the webapps runtime. Reloading resets all of these memory allocations and reinitializes the webapp from scratch.

It's the responsibility of technologies like localStorage, sessionStorage, IndexedDB or even Cookies to persist this data across reloads.

Comment: Is it safe to store data in ocalStorage, sessionStorage ? One can easily change data stored in localStorage or session Storage.

Comment: Under no circumstances should you persist sensitive data in localStorage. You must always treat data loaded from localStorage as potentially malicious user input.